# Steam Login API with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, steam, steam-web-api

I was wondering if there is a steam login authentication script that can be used along side socket.io I have found some login API's but most are outdated and the developers will not speak to me. If anyone knows a javascript steam API that works well with socket.io so I can send info to and from the client please tell me where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The steam login API works through OAuth. You can see a working implementation of Steam OAuth [here](https://github.com/cpancake/steam-login). In terms of getting that to work with socket.io, the question doesn't really make sense. Socket.IO is a messaging system that can be used to send short messages between the client and server. OAuth requires the user to go to the steam website to login (otherwise, there would be a security risk). Steam doesn't support Socket.io for login, so there is no way to login using OAuth.

If you are talking about server-side and believe that it will increase performance, it won't. Socket.io works exactly the same as HTTP(S), sometimes even over HTTP, and so it again doesn't make sense to even try to use socket.io.